# Editing a matrix field on the front end

Tags: matrix

I'm sorry if this has already been asked, the new EE answers thing is so overly confusing to me, I'm almost considering private exchanges via email but thought I'd just ask here first.

All I want to do is to edit a Matrix field from the front end. This is my code, but all it's doing is adding a new row. Any thoughts?

```
{therapist_employcompany sort="desc" limit="1"}
   <input type="hidden" name="therapist_employcompany[row_order][]" value="row_id_{row_id}">
   <input type="text" name="therapist_employcompany[row_id_{row_id}][col_id_48]" value="{therapist_employcompany} "/>
{/therapist_employcompany}
```

I thought by bringing in the row ID dynamically it would update it, but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome. 
If you use the search box, you will find 261 questions relating to matrix.
To embed code, paste the code in, highlight it then select the curly brackets.
The secret with matrix is the input field names. In the control panel, edit an entry then find the matrix field in the source code. Now do the same thing on a new entry. Note the differences in field name.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is not straightforward, to be sure. However, here's a good tutorial: http://themetaq.com/articles/bring-matrix-data-editing-to-the-front-end